# How does ffmpeg extract audio data from mp3 files?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

In the ffmpeg documentation, an example of [mp2 decoding](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode_audio_8c-example.html) is given. I try to apply this to mp3:

```cpp
#define SOURCE_FILE "ignore/audio01.mp3"
#define TARGET_FILE "ignore/target-audio01.pcm"
#define AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE 20480
#define AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH 4096
#define av_perr(errnum) \
    char av_err_buff[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE]; \
    av_strerror(errnum, (char *) &av_err_buff, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE); \
    fprintf(stderr, "\033[91m%s\033[0m\n", av_err_buff);

static int decode(AVCodecContext *dec_ctx, AVPacket *pkt, AVFrame *frame, FILE *outfile) {
    int ret, i, j;
    int data_size;

    ret = avcodec_send_packet(dec_ctx, pkt);
    if (ret < 0) {
        av_perr(ret);
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while (ret >= 0) {
        ret = avcodec_receive_frame(dec_ctx, frame);
        if (ret == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || ret == AVERROR_EOF) {
            break;
        } else if (ret < 0) {
            av_perr(ret);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        data_size = av_get_bytes_per_sample(dec_ctx->sample_fmt);
        if (data_size < 0) {
            av_perr(data_size);
            return EXIT_FAILURE;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < frame->nb_samples; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < dec_ctx->channels; j++) {
                fwrite(frame->data[j] + data_size * i, 1, data_size, outfile);
            }
        }
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

#define IS_NULL_PTR(ptr, message) \
    if (!ptr) { \
        fprintf(stderr, "\033[91m%s\033[0m\n", message); \
        goto FINALLY; \
    }
#define av_perr(errnum) \
    char av_err_buff[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE]; \
    av_strerror(errnum, (char *) &av_err_buff, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE); \
    fprintf(stderr, "\033[91m%s\033[0m\n", av_err_buff);

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    const AVCodec *codec;
    AVCodecContext *c = nullptr;
    AVCodecParserContext *parser = nullptr;
    enum AVSampleFormat sfmt;

    int ret = 0, len = 0, n_channels = 0;
    FILE *source_file = nullptr, *target_file = nullptr;
    const char *fmt = nullptr;
    uint8_t inbuf[AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE + AV_INPUT_BUFFER_PADDING_SIZE];
    uint8_t *data = nullptr;
    size_t data_size = 0;
    AVPacket *pkt = nullptr;
    AVFrame *decode_frame = nullptr;

    ...

    data = inbuf;
    data_size = fread(inbuf, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE, source_file);
    while (data_size > 0) {
        ret = av_parser_parse2(parser, c, &pkt->data, &pkt->size, data, data_size, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, AV_NOPTS_VALUE, 0);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "\033[91mError while parsing\033[0m\n");
            goto FINALLY;
        }
        data += ret;
        data_size -= ret;
        if (pkt->size && decode(c, pkt, decode_frame, target_file)) goto FINALLY;

        if (data_size < AUDIO_REFILL_THRESH) {
            memmove(inbuf, data, data_size);
            data = inbuf;
            len = fread(data + data_size, 1, AUDIO_INBUF_SIZE - data_size, source_file);
            if (len > 0) data_size += len;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

I get these errors:

```
[mp3float @ 0x55c51ac63440] Header missing
Invalid data found when processing input
```

Here is the version of the ffmpeg library:

```
libavutil      57. 17.100 / 57. 17.100
libavcodec     59. 18.100 / 59. 18.100
libavformat    59. 16.100 / 59. 16.100
libavdevice    59.  4.100 / 59.  4.100
libavfilter     8. 24.100 /  8. 24.100
libswscale      6.  4.100 /  6.  4.100
libswresample   4.  3.100 /  4.  3.100
libpostproc    56.  3.100 / 56.  3.100
```

I guess this is due to the fundamental difference in the data format of the mp3 and mp2 frames, but I can't find a way to decode the mp3.

What is the essential difference between the audio formats of mp3 and mp2? Also, what can I do to properly handle mp3 audio?

Comment: See this tutorial: http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial03.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check if the input MP3 file starts with ID3 tag (pretty sure it does). FFMPEG does pretty awful job with skipping metadata that is not defined by particular codec standard. Thus, `av_parser_parse2()` would not skip ID3 tags and then `avcodec_send_packet()` would complain about data you fed it with (since it doesn't recognize ID3 metadata as a valid MP3 stream).

See https://id3.org/id3v2.3.0#ID3v2_header for more information about ID3 header - parse it properly and its size is all you need to skip the rest of ID3 tag. The simplest thing to do is to read first 10 bytes of the file and check for ID3 tag, if present - parse size of the rest of the tag and just seek this many bytes ahead in the input file. From that point you can read rest of the file and pass its content to FFMPEG functions normally, as in example.